# R: Rearranging code / Loops for Confusion Matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, prediction, confusion-matrix

I am basically trying to work a confusion matrix with some prediction / response variables under a couple of conditions, but im not sure how to lay out the code.

for my prediction values, my current code is:

```
Prediction <- factor (rep(data$percentage <=40.0 || data$binary ==1,levels=c("TRUE","FALSE")))
```

but I am pretty sure this is incorrect because what I want to achieve is the following conditions:

- if percentage is <=40 then consider this as TRUE
- but if percentage is shown as NA then refer to data$binary column
- based on this, if data$binary = 1, then consider this as TRUE.

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: could you try ; prediction <- ifelse(data$percentage <= 40 | data$binary==1,TRUE,ifelse(is.na(data$percentage) | is.na(data$binary),NA,FALSE))

Comment: Hey thanks for this, my binary column only contains 0,1 (i.e never has a NA) would this still work?

Comment: yup, as you see I put an `or` operator (`|`) between two conditions, no worries if `binary` column has no `NA` , it is enough to have any `NA` in both columns to assign `NA` to `prediction` vector. if this fixes your problem properly, let me know then I will put my answer as a real answer, then you can approve.

Comment: Just ran the code with your suggestion but still has to same output as my own code earlier on :'( would you suggest any other changes to be made? I think its still having difficulty with 2 conditions of:  1) if percentage is shown as NA then refer to data$binary column and 2) based on this, if data$binary = 1, then consider this as TRUE.

Comment: have you tried to use `and` (`&`) operator ? or just functionalize what you want; let me transcript down side what I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not to hard code, I worked directly on your data frame;

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
mutate(logistic_column=rowSums(data)) %>% 
mutate(prediction=ifelse(is.na(logistic_column),
                         ifelse(binary==1,TRUE,FALSE),
                         ifelse(percentage<=40,TRUE,FALSE))) %>% 
select(prediction) %>% 
pull -> prediction
```

Comment: Thank you does the job!